# LINQ Exception: "Queries with local collections are not supported." but not using a local collection

Tags: linq, exception, datacontext

Using the AdventureWorks database's Products table as the example, I have created a DBML and extended the properties of the DataContext to include a new property:

```
partial class AdventureWorksDataContext
{
  public IQueryable<Product> FinishedProducts
  {
    get { return Products.Where(p => p.FinishedGoodsFlag); }
  }
}
```

The Products property is part of the generated DataContext and all I've done is add a Where from the Table<Product> so it returns an IQueryable.

Now, the problem comes in when trying to query it like this (dumb example but one that should show the problem):

`var queryFinishedProducts = datacontext.FinishedProducts.Where(fp => fp.ProductID == datacontext.FinishedProducts.Max(p => p.ProductID));`

Iterating this query results in "Queries with local collections are not supported" exception. I don't understand why it would throw that error when there are no local collections being used. If I run it against the normal Products table (which is a `Table<Product>`):

`var queryProducts = datacontext.FinishedProducts.Where(fp => fp.ProductID == datacontext.Products.Max(p => p.ProductID));`

...it works fine. The only difference is that I added a Where to the `Table<Product>` and returned it as an `IQueryable<Product>`.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Is FinishedProducts a property?  Where's the "get"?

Comment: Yes, it is a property. Sorry, I'll add the get for clarity.

Comment: It looks like maybe the SQL generator was unable to tell that the `Products` used in the FinishedProducts` query came from the same `DataContext` as the rest of the query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach that should work:

```
var max = datacontext.FinishedProducts.Max(p => p.ProductID);
var queryFinishedProducts = datacontext.FinishedProducts
                                       .Where(fp => fp.ProductID == max);
```

Or assuming that `ProductID` is unique try rewriting your query as follows:

```
var queryProducts = datacontext.FinishedProducts
                               .OrderByDescending(p => p.ProductID)
                               .First();
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, however I was looking more for a reason why LINQ would process what is essentially the same query differently. The query was really just an example of a larger problem, with that being the lambda being able to use what is essentially a sub-SELECT.

Comment: @Mike: I think the difference is because `Products` not just an `IQueryable<T>`, it is a `Table<T>`.

Comment: I dug into the innards of the Table and DataQuery classes with Reflector and Table just implements the CreateQuery methods and returns a DataQuery whenever an extension method is used. Having said that, this: Products.Where(p => p) should be equal to a property that returns the same statement, which is what the example shows. And that's what I don't understand is how passing an IQueryable back using the Products property is different.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this behavior.  Here's a couple more types to look at in reflector:

```
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor
```

Based on this stack trace.

```
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlBinder.Visitor.ConvertToFetchedSequence(SqlNode node)
at ..SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a)
at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
at ..SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
at ..SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
at ..SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
at ..SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitAlias(SqlAlias a)
at ..SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
at ..SqlVisitor.VisitSource(SqlSource source)
at ..SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitSelect(SqlSelect select)
at ..SqlVisitor.Visit(SqlNode node)
at ..SqlVisitor.VisitSequence(SqlSelect sel)
at ..SqlVisitor.VisitScalarSubSelect(SqlSubSelect ss)
at ..SqlVisitor.VisitSubSelect(SqlSubSelect ss)
at ..SqlBinder.Visitor.VisitSubSelect(SqlSubSelect ss)
```

I wonder why a property of type `Table<T>` is treated differently than a property of type `IQueryable<T>` or even `ITable<T>`.  The implementation of the property doesn't matter, the return type matters.

---

A property of type `IQueryable<T>` is definately treated differently than a locally scoped variable of type `IQueryable<T>`

```
IQueryable<Customer> query1 =
  myDC.Customers.Where(c => c.ID == myDC.CoolCustomers.Max(c2 => c2.ID));

IQueryable<Customer> query2 =
  myDC.Customers.Where(c => c.ID == myDC.Customers.Where(c2 => c2.Flag).Max(c2 => c2.ID));

IQueryable<Customer> subQuery = myDC.CoolCustomers;
IQueryable<Customer> query3 =
  myDC.Customers.Where(c => c.ID == subQuery.Max(c2 => c2.ID));
```

query1 exhibits the original behavior (exception, local sequences).

query2 generates this sql - less than ideal.

```
SELECT [t0].[ID], [t0].[Flag]
FROM [Customer] AS [t0]
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT MAX([t1].[ID]) AS [value]
    FROM [Customer] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[Flag] = 1
    ) AS [t2]
WHERE [t0].[ID] = [t2].[value]
```

query3 over-eagerly issues the subquery during query translation, then makes a second roundtrip for the main query.

Comment: Thanks for digging that deep into the LINQ framework! I just wish I understood why it's treated differently. I'll start digging at those classes and see what else I can find. Really hoping this isn't the first time this has come up though, it seems like something that any large project might do to pre-filter the table properties.